# How to execute command without using the do command twice in the loop

Tags: loops, shell, for-loop

These are my files

```
KIMS2021-01_R1.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-05_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734376_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006897_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006901_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006905_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-01_R2.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-05_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734376_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006897_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006901_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006905_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-02_R1.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-06_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734377_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006898_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006902_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006906_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-02_R2.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-06_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734377_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006898_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006902_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006906_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-03_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734374_1.fastq.gz    SRR6006895_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006899_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006903_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-03_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734374_2.fastq.gz    SRR6006895_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006899_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006903_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-04_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734375_1.fastq.gz    SRR6006896_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006900_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006904_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-04_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734375_2.fastq.gz    SRR6006896_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006900_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006904_2.fastq.gz
```

To get uniform file name for each pair i got this answer from my previous question
which is this

```
for i in $(echo *.fastq*.gz); do echo ${i%_*}; done | uniq
```

My final command which i want to use after I get uniform file name

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz); do echo ${i%_*}; done | uniq; do STAR --runMode alignReads --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --runThreadN 30 --genomeDir /run/media/punit/data3/Santosh_star_index --readFilesIn  <(gunzip -c ${i}_R1.fastq.gz ${i}_R2.fastq.gz ) --outFileNamePrefix ${i%};done
```

Now i understand i can;t use `do`  twice in a loop

How to pass the uniform file name to my command without using `do` twice

Comment: I don't see the point in using `echo`. It not only creates an unnecessary child process, it will even produce wrong results if you have filenames with embedded spaces. Why don't you simply do a `for i in *.fastq*.gz`

Comment: The `do STAR ...` does not make sense. Didn't you get a _syntax error_ there?

Comment: yes thats why the question ..i have to use the file name to pass to the aligner the issue is due to non uniform file name .had it been a pattern like only SRR  i was good to go with the command

Comment: user1934428 in my previous  question i got suggestion for echo since its safer than ls

Comment: It is correct that you should not use `ls`, but replacing one nonsense by a different one, is also of no help. With both `echo` and `ls`, you get in trouble with filenames, which contain either spaces or newlines. So don't do this.

Comment: okay ..i did some search if i learn and run like nextflow it would be easier for file handling i guess..the naming issue is not that complicated there i guess looking at the examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from my previous question which is this

For starters let's fix it! Do not do:

```
for i in $(anything); do
```

Just do:

```
for i in *.fastq*.gz; do
```

> How to pass the uniform file name to my command

Shell most importantly works with *pipes* `|`. The output of one command is input to another - like in your pipe, the output of `for` loop is the input of `uniq`.

Read the output of uniq.

```
for i in *.fastq*.gz; do echo "${i%_*}"; done |
   uniq |
   while IFS= read -r file; do stuff with "$file"; done
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.net . See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

> as a biologist its a pain for me do dig the basic nuances of the scripting my simple solution would be if i run the them as two sets

Sure! I do that when interactive scripting a lot.

```
tmp=$( for i in *.fastq*.gz; do echo "${i%_*}"; done )
tmp=$( uniq <<<"$tmp" )   # or tmp=$( echo "$tmp" | uniq )
tmp=$( echo "$tmp" | while IFS= read -r file; do stuff with "$file"; done )
echo "$tmp"
```

Remember about qoutes `"`! `<<<"stuff"` works like `<file` - inputs the content of `"stuff"` to the input of the command, does the same as `echo "$tmp" |`.

Comment: so here you have used do twice it is works only when it is use with 'while ' pardon my ignorance

Comment: Uuuhm, yes, the keyword `do` must be preceded with `for` or `while`, it has to be `for ....; do` or `while ....; do`. Each pipeline element is a separate command, and `for` and `while` (and `if` and `case` and `until` and groups `(...)` `{...}`) count as one command. `( a=example; echo $a; ) | ( read var; echo "This is $var" )`

Comment: @PesKchan : Doing just lexical analysis, you may be right, but the point is that two _loops_ are involved, and the designers of bash have decided in their infinite wisdom, that each loop (`for` and `while`) must include the word _do_. You may want to search for a solution containing a single loop only, though I don't see any benifit.

Comment: as a biologist its a pain for me do dig the basic nuances of the scripting my simple solution would be if i run the them as two sets ..

Comment: `if i run the them as two sets` updated

Comment: will try to run thanks for the kind of extensive explanation